# How to make each video clone fullscreen on its monitor in VLC?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I have two monitors connected to my pc. I want to watch two clones of a video, both fullscreen on their own monitor. I configure VLC to clone the video window, and drag one of the windows to the other monitor (with extended desktop). Now I can only maximize the two windows, but not watch them fullscreen. The Windows taskbar and the window title bar are still visible (see image below).

[image: VLC clone image]

How to display two clones of a video fullscreen each on a monitor?

PS: I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: I wish I knew! This used to be possible on an older version of VLC (1.x, I think?). Then one day I upgraded and the ability to fullscreen clones was just gone.